# How to add the directory to classpath with jetty-maven-plugin 9.x?

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

My Maven project was using jetty-maven-plugin version 7 and I used to add the directory to Jetty's classpath by specifying "extraClasspath" parameter in "webAppConfig", like here:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.1.v20091125</version>
  <configuration>
    <webAppConfig>
      <contextPath>/</contextPath>
      <extraClasspath>${basedir}/src/profiles/jetty</extraClasspath>
    </webAppConfig>
    <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Today I decided to update to the recent version of jetty-maven-plugin and I found that there is no "extraClasspath" parameter anymore.

How could I add the directory to the classpath with last version of jetty-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it moved... this is how I got it working:

```
<webApp>
    <extraClasspath>${basedir}/local/properties</extraClasspath>
</webApp>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time with this. Somethings moved and Jetty not complains/warns about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949206/jetty-maven-plugin-put-properties-file-in-classpath

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-maven-plugin.html, this should work to add a resource directory **in addition to** webapp:

> **`resourceBases`**
>
> Use instead of `baseResource` if you have multiple dirs from which you want to serve static content. This is an array of dir names.

If you only wanted to change the base directory, you'd use:

> **`baseResource`**
>
> The path from which Jetty serves static resources. Defaults to `src/main/webapp`.

This is how I implemented `resourceBases` to include a directory *in addition to* `src/main/webapp`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/pf</contextPath>
            <descriptor>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
            <resourceBases>
                <baseResource>src/main/webapp</baseResource>
                <baseResource>some/other/directory</baseResource>
            </resourceBases>
        </webApp>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The question is about adding the directory to *classpath*, not to the resources.