# Jetty Maven plugin - Put properties file in classpath

Tags: classpath, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm using the eclipse jetty plugin in my project:

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
```

I have my application that read a **file** in the *classpath* of the server, but I can't manage to put it in the Jetty classpath...

I would to put it in a folder in my project and make that folder part of the Jetty classpath, how can I do it?
Is there a better solution to make that file external to the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was just a matter of configuration of the maven plugin

```
<configuration>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <jettyXml>jetty/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
    <webApp>
        <extraClasspath>${basedir}/jetty/classpath</extraClasspath>
    </webApp>
</configuration>
```

to add a *classpath* folder to Jetty, it needs the **extraClasspath** folder in the **webApp** tag.